# Can't get addObject to work on NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to add UIButton objects to an array, but they fail to do so. Whenever I call [pixels count] or [colors count] it returns 0. I tried using [self.arrayName addObject:myObject] and [arrayName addObject:myObject] but neither seem to work. I'm pretty new to Objective-C so it probably seems dumb on my part, but this has been stumping me for over an hour.

Here is the code for ViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
 NSMutableArray *pixels;
 NSMutableArray *colors;
 }
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pixels;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *colors;
 @end
```

And here is the relevant code from ViewController.m

```
 int x = 30;
 int y = 60;
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
      UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,20,20)];
      [self.pixels addObject:button];
      x += 20;
      y += 20;
 }
```

I have the whole project zipped up which can be downloaded here:
http://mdl.fm/pixelated.zip

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Did you ever initialize your arrays?

Comment: Where would I initialize them? I tried in ViewController.h but it keeps saying Expected ";" at end of declaration list. I also tried it inside of init() on ViewController.m and inside of viewDidLoad() on ViewController.m but neither worked.

Comment: Right, nil targered messages are ignored (except for NSControl).

Comment: If you get a useful answer at this site, you're supposed to click the checkmark by the one that answers your question. I see you haven't done that yet on your 4 questions. Maybe you haven't gotten a good answer yet.

Comment: Not a problem, we all have to learn some time. But it still looks like an open question. You need to click the checkmark to say "I accept this answer." You should do this for any answers you got on other questions that you consider correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this in before you try to use the arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *pixels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Arrays in Obj-C need to be initialized before being used. Since calling methods on a nil instance just returns zero in Obj-C, it's easy to do this and not notice until your array isn't storing what you think it should.

Edit to add info from comments:

You can put the initialization into the `-ViewDidLoad` method, so that they are ready to go once the `ViewController` itself is ready. Make sure you `retain` them, so they don't get automatically garbage-collected.

Comment: But as @rdelmar pointed out, where it is done is as important as doing it.

Comment: Where would you recommend putting this? If I put it inside of viewDidLoad it will only be available inside of that method. I have another question as well. When I use [colors addObject:colorObject] it adds to the array fine, but it gives me a warning message saying "Local declaration of 'colors' hides instance variable". I can get rid of the error by changing it to [self.colors addObject:colorObject] but then it doesn't add to the array. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Change the name of the array from "colors" to something less likely to collide with other variable names. For example, ColorArr.

Comment: @noname If you put your initialization in -`viewDidLoad`, and make the assignments to your `pixels` and `colors` ivars (and make sure they're retained), of course they'll be available elsewhere.

Comment: Don't synthesize colors and call self.colors when need that instance variable.

Comment: It really is better practice not to hide variable names. It leads to confusing code.

Answer (score 2):

You initialized pixels in an init method -- init is not called for a controller you set up in a storyboard. Either change that to initWithCoder: or move your array initializations to viewDidLoad.